# How to get the last element with querySelector?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm scraping from a website that has a lot of nested HTML elements, but what interests me are the `abbr` elements. In my case those `abbr` elements have `data-utime` attribute, so they are defined as `<abbr data-utime="someValue">some other nested HTML</abbr>`. So, what I want to do is that I want to get the `data-utime` attribute value of the last `abbr` element on the page.

I tried to do something like this:

```
const SELECTOR = 'abbr:last-child';
const result = await page.evaluate((selector) => {
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}, SELECTOR);

console.log(result);
console.log(typeof(res));
console.log(result.getAttribute('data-utime'));
```

But the problem is that in the output that I get, `result` is just an empty object (`{}`), so `typeof(res)` returns object, and it of course doesn't have `getAttribute` function then. I believe also `last-child` selector is the proper way to get the last `abbr` element on the page. Any ideas how to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`evaluate` is run in the page’s context; the result is serialized and returned. Use `$$eval` instead:

```
const SELECTOR = "abbr";
const result =
      await page.$$eval(SELECTOR,
                        (elements) => elements[elements.length - 1].dataset.utime);
console.log(result);
```

You can also use `evaluate` and call `document.querySelectorAll` inside it, but I prefer to keep the selectors in my Puppeteer code so I can reuse them.

Comment: I believe `document.$$eval` should be `page.$$eval` in my case.

Comment: Oops, yes, sorry. Rewrote it in a hurry because I incorrectly suggested `evaluateHandle`.

Comment: Glad to hear it!